# php reading from an icecast 2 server with multiple mount points

Tags: php, html, xslt, icecast

I am trying to build a now playing script that allows me to show now playing information on a page reading from an Icecast server that contains multiple mount points. so far whatever I have used either reads only the first mountpoint, or breaks completely trying to parse the output.

Right now the icecast status2.xsl url I am trying to read from formats like so:

```
MountPoint,Connections,Stream Name,Current Listeners,Description,Currently Playing,Stream     URL 
Global,Client:242366 Source: ,,,,
/radio1,,,0,, - ,/radio6,,,2,, - Olympic Runners - Put the Music Where Your Mouth Is,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this in the past - https://code.google.com/p/icecast-now-playing-script/